# How do i get normal encrypted string

Tags: php, encryption

I m getting captcha encrypted value in my input like:

```
value="     JFIF         &gt;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default      quality
   C $.' &quot;,#(7),01444'9=82&lt;.342    C2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222    ( x&quot;           

   } !1AQa &quot;q2   #B  R  $3br %&amp;'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz                                                                            
   w !1AQ aq&quot;2 B     #3R br 
$4 % &amp;'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz                                                                             ?   Ԓ 61N 7I v n     %   O;pHU   C8Xn   &quot;  + 8   s c NNGw e ֱx4裴   Ԡ;+ uv i  Q ea @@     [ o H.       D!K7 6 ) CR nq   t3m  O R   g$  L  Ź `:ǘ s6   n| U PC   h M         7y F W     X    R RX8u  c \c )]  kw$ p _ w    &gt; 5    ˩P ̪ 4h? .7n Th +mbn\ ,    ][Ķ|   I$pe &quot;
```

How do i get normal encrypted string like 'CDEF01jhdfz' instead of above string? I think its a problem of encryption.. here is my code:

```
    function str_encrypt( $str ) {
       $mystr = index_array( $str, KEY_VALUES );
       $mystr = mybase64_encode( rawurlencode( $mystr ) );
       return $mystr;
    }
    function str_decrypt( $str ) {
       $mystr = rawurldecode( mybase64_decode( $str ) ) ;
       $mystr = index_array( $mystr, KEY_VALUES );
       return $mystr;
    }  
    $captcha = new CaptchaCode();
    $code = str_encrypt( $captcha->generateCode(6) );
    $captcha1 = new CaptchaImages();
    $captcha1->GenerateImage( $width, $height, str_decrypt( $code ) );
    echo $code;

i m getting $code value through below function on my index.php:

    jQuery.get('<?php echo captcha_images.php ?>', function( encoded_code ) {
        jQuery('#security_check').val( encoded_code );
    }
```

Comment: That's not an "encrypted" string, that's JPG data.

Comment: Ok then how can i get encrypted data? my image in captcha display perfect.

Comment: More precisely, it's an HTML-encoded JPEG picture. Honestly, I don't think you can get back your original binary data once you've cast it to plain text. Why do you need that? All captcha systems I've used use an alphanumeric code to identify the challenge and, apparently, yours too. Did you follow the usage instructions provided by the author?

Comment: In my captcha image there is alphanumeric code, but at the time of comparison of the user entered text with captcha code i want that encrypted data which right now m get as i shown above.. i want a normal encrypted string instead of that JPG data

Comment: Is this your real code? `<?php echo captcha_images.php ?>` should trigger a notice. And it's strange that `echo $code;` prints the image...

Comment: captcha.php is a file from where image is generating with the encrpted code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a complex code, I usually pass the code via session.

The image_captcha.php creates a code like: 19m92d9193jf9. You could use md5() to generate it and a substr() to make it short.

Show an image with this code, then set this value in a session variable.

So the current php file can get this value without more efforts. Just access the image.

image_captcha.php

```
    $basepath = DIR_VIEWS.'/captcha/';

    $code = substr(md5(time()),0,7);

    $_SESSION['code_captcha'] = $code;

    $imageCaptcha = imagecreatefrompng($basepath."background.png");
    $fontCaptcha = imageloadfont($basepath."anonymous.gdf");

    $color = imagecolorallocate($imageCaptcha,rand(1,255),0,0);

    imagestring($imageCaptcha,$fontCaptcha,15,rand(3,10),$codigoCaptcha{0},$color);
    imagestring($imageCaptcha,$fontCaptcha,35,rand(3,10),$codigoCaptcha{1},$color);
    imagestring($imageCaptcha,$fontCaptcha,55,rand(3,10),$codigoCaptcha{2},$color);
    imagestring($imageCaptcha,$fontCaptcha,75,rand(3,10),$codigoCaptcha{3},$color);
    imagestring($imageCaptcha,$fontCaptcha,125,rand(3,10),$codigoCaptcha{4},$color);
    imagestring($imageCaptcha,$fontCaptcha,145,rand(3,10),$codigoCaptcha{5},$color);
    imagestring($imageCaptcha,$fontCaptcha,165,rand(3,10),$codigoCaptcha{6},$color);

    header("Content-type: image/png");

    imagepng($imageCaptcha);
    imagedestroy($imageCaptcha);
    exit();
```

Access this file:

```
<img src="image_captcha.php"/>
```

Here the captcha code is ready to check.

Comment: i have to do this without session and cookies

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code and comments, you have an undisclosed script called `captcha_images.php` that generates and sends a raw JPEG picture. You then fit it into an HTWML attribute with client-side JavaScript.

The [`jQuery.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value) expects **plain text**:

> .val( value )
>
> ```
> value
> Type: String or Array
> ```
>
> A string of text or an array of strings corresponding to the value of each matched element to set as selected/checked.

... which makes perfect sense because HTML itself is not a binary format at all:

```
Content-Type: text/html
              ^^^^
```

This means that it's impossible to get back your original binary data afterwards. The process of converting it to text will destroy it.

I don't know what *«normal encrypted string»* means but you should probably be sending it from the server ready to use.

Comment: could u please tell me how to use get new value each time of php variable through session. here is some code: session_start();
 $_SESSION['code_captcha'] = $code; $code generates new value each time when i click on refresh image, but i m getting its value only once..how can i repeatedly get its value